# WCF, not closing connection results timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, azure

We use asp.net MVC to consume WCF Relay Service hosted in Azure. Works fine in staging but getting exceptions below in Production when user tries to renew the membership.

> 1. service has exceeded the allotted timeout of 00:02:00. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer
>      timeout.*
> 2. System.ServiceModel.FaultException: 50400: Gateway Timeout.*

Below is the snippet of code we use:

```
Autofac DI:

builder.Register(c => new MyServiceClient("BasicHttpRelayBinding_IMyService")).As<IMyService>();
```

Service Layer:

```
try
            {
                var response= this.myServiceClient.GetData();                }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                this.loggerService.Error("some log");
                throw;
            }
```

As you can see we are not explicitly closing the service connection. Could this be causing the timeout issue?

Also if you could help me with below will be good:

1. Does WCF closes the connection by default?
2. Should we get different error if connection was not closed?

Comment: It's a good idea to *always* explicitly close a WCF connection (channel), rather than allowing it to timeout, as this can cause all sorts of fun (and difficult to diagnose) problems in the long run.   WCF does not close the connection itself unless it times out.   Also, be aware that you cannot close a channel that has faulted, it must be aborted.

Comment: How do we achieve this (i.e. Close the channel) given that we are using DI to instantiate the service?  Also do we need to explicitly close the basicHttpRelay binding or only applies to TCP binding.